# how to pass Bitmap from Fragment to Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bitmap

**strong text**App have a fragment that contains image and i want to pass the image to activity use Bitmap when i click to set this image as wallpaper.

From **Fragment** :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, null);
        ImageView resultView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_image);

        resultView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = resultView.getDrawingCache();

        resultView.setImageResource(pageNumber);
        return view;
    }
```

To **Activity**, when i click to set:

```
        case R.id.setForce:

                new TaskSetWallpaper(PreviewActivity.this).execute(bitmap);

                break;
```

Comment: You must be getting some URL or URI of which you are converting it into bitmap and setting it to imageview.
Pass that URL / URI through interface callback to your activity, because passing bitmap will sometimes lead you application to crash due to out of memory exception.

Comment: @Ajinkya S thanks, your answer helped me to better understand my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface in your fragment, which the parent activity of the fragment is expected to implement. Then, you can cast the activity to the interface in `onAttach()` of the fragment and call methods in the interface to notify events or pass data to parent activity.

Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private EventListener eventListener;

    public interface EventListener() {
        void onSetImage(Bitmap bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity a) {
        super.onAttach(a);
        if (a instanceof EventListener) {
            eventListener = (EventListener) a;
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parent activity should implement MyFragment.EventListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Parent activity:

```
public class ParentActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.EventListener {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //---------
        //---------
    }

    @Override
    void onSetImage(Bitmap bitmap){
        new TaskSetWallpaper(PreviewActivity.this).execute(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! it helped me, I only change `@Override
    public void onSetImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
    }` for pass bitmap when i click to set `case R.id.setForce:
                new TaskSetWallpaper(PreviewActivity.this).execute(mBitmap);
                break;`